# window.parent.document working in firefox , but not in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

My concept is to update the value of the text box in the main page from the iframe . This code is working in `firefox` , but not working in `Internet Explorer` and `Chrome` . Both `main.html` and `frame.html` are in same location . I need suggestions to make it work in all the browsers .

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> main window </title>
</head>
<body>
Parent textbox :<input type="text" id="parentbox"></br></br></br>
<iframe src="frame.html" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

frame.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> frame window </title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function PushValues()
{
 var frame_value = document.getElementById("framebox").value;
 window.parent.document.getElementById("parentbox").value =frame_value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="framebox" >
<input type="button" value ="fill" onclick="PushValues()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: did you try `window.top.document`

Comment: The code worked fine as-is for me in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE, although you should really close your <iframe> tag.

Comment: @Chris I do have a closing tag for iframe , I just missed it here . Could you please tell me your browser versions .

Comment: @Cherniv Am getting the following errors in Chrome console .
 1.`Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null".` 
2.`Protocols, domains, and ports must match. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined .`

Answer (score 2):

As per security policies, cross-domain access is restricted. This will happen if you are trying to show a page from domain 1 in domain 2 and try to manipulate the DOM of page in domain 2 from the script in domain 1. If you are running the pages from same location on a server. This shouldn't happen. However, if you are just saving them as HTML files and trying to open them in your browser, it should not work. I have created two jsbins for your code and it is working on chrome. Try to access them using the below links.

Main.html: http://jsbin.com/afazEDE/1
iframe.html: http://jsbin.com/ayacEXa/1/

Try to run main.html in edit mode in JSBin by keeping console open in chrome (F12) and click fill button. It will not work and will show you the error. If you run them as it is (in run mode of JSBin), it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery  -

```
function PushValues()
{
  var frame_value = $('#framebox').val();
  parent.$('body').find('#parentbox').val(frame_value);
}
```

It's always work for me.

Comment: and what if the `parent` isn't includes jQuery?

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to say. This code is write into "IFrame", so there is always a parent of an "IFrame".

Comment: You're right , `parent` is always exist. But `parent.$` - not 100% exist!

Comment: Yes, you are right. If the parent window isn't includes jQuery file that's create problem.

Comment: Works in IE for me , but not in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

**Run this code on a server like xamp or wamp it wont work directly**

**Main.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> main window </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Parent textbox :<input type="text" id="parentbox" value=""></br></br></br>
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    <script>
        window._fn = {
            printval: function (response) {
                $("input").val(response);
            },
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

**iframe**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> frame window </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="framebox">
    <input type="button" value="fill" onclick="PushValues()">

    <script language="javascript">
        function PushValues() {
            window.parent._fn['printval']($('input').val());
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: well just found that even your code works fine just that it needs to be run on a server level to avoid cross domain issues of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery try this

```
var frame_value = $('#framebox').val();
$('#parentbox', window.parent.document).val(frame_value);
```

Comment: I tried this , thats why i had that jqery . even this works in firefox alone not in chrome .

Comment: @user2564024 Then you should take a look at it http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

You should try P3P policy which is highly related to iframes and Internet Explorer.
response header set to the iframe document

```
header key= 'P3P'   header value: 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'
```